# Removing member variable from Entity Framework Core generated class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core to generate classes from a SQL database and am trying to remove some navigation member variables from some of my classes. For example, here is one of the class that were generated:

```
public class SerialNumbers
{
    public SerialNumbers()
    {
        Features = new HashSet<Features>();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Serial Number ID
    /// </summary>
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Contracts Id
    /// </summary>
    public Guid ContractId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The User's ID
    /// </summary>
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Features> Features { get; set; }


    public virtual Contracts Contract { get; set; }

    public virtual Users User { get; set; }
```

How would I go about removing the navigation variables Contract and User as they aren't needed for what I'm doing? If I just remove them, I get a SQL exception when calling LINQ methods.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the data model?  There you can remove the navigation properties and then update the business objects.

Comment: I haven't yet, is there anyway you can clarify more by what you mean by that?

Comment: There should be a sub folder within the project that has the data models for these objects.  When you open up the data model there you will see navigation properties as like a sub-category under the specific object.  You can right-click the nav properties and remove.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean by this, since I am using Entity Framework Core I don't see the data model but instead have a DevContext class to create the relationship between objects

Comment: Yes, that could be it.  Haven't touched Entity Framework Core, but that's how you would fix the issue in Entity Framework.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help anyway, I'll try to find the parallels between the two and hopefully that'll point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: If I remove the Users variable, I get an error saying the UsersId column is Invalid, but that table does not exist in the database.

Comment: It should be noted that UserID is a foreign key from the Users table